# Найти самый длинный путь (наибольшая сумма веса ребер) в графе

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы

Как можно изменить алгоритм Дейкстры (Dijkstra), чтобы найти самый длинный путь (наибольшая сумма веса ребер) в графе от определенной стартовой вершины, пройдя все вершины. Или какой другой алгоритм можно использовать? Граф без циклов и без ребер с отрицательным весом. 
Например для графа представленного в виде данной матрицы смежности:

0 1 1 0

1 0 0 1

1 0 0 0

0 1 0 0

Стартовая вершина 1.

На выходе необходимо получить приблизительно в таком формате ответ:

The worst case scenario:

1. 1->3 (1 unit of time)
2. 1->2 (1 unit of time)
3. 2->4 (1 unit of time)
   The total time is 3 units of time

The best case scenario:

1. 1->2 (1 unit of time)
2. 1->3 and2->4(1 unit of time)
   The total time is 2 units of time.

У меня есть вот такой код алгоритма Дейкстры:

```
public class Dij {
    private static int INF = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;
    protected int n; //количество вершин в орграфе 
    protected int m; //количествое дуг в орграфе 
    private ArrayList<Integer> adj[]; //список смежности 
    private ArrayList<Integer> weight[]; //вес ребра в орграфе 
    private boolean used[]; //массив для хранения информации о пройденных и не пройденных вершинах 
    private int dist[]; //массив для хранения расстояния от стартовой вершины 
    private int pred[]; //массив предков, необходимых для восстановления кратчайшего пути из стартовой вершины 
    int start; //стартовая вершина, от которой ищется расстояние до всех других 
    private StringTokenizer tokenizer;
    Result res;
    protected String p;
    protected String k;

    //процедура запуска алгоритма Дейкстры из стартовой вершины 
    private void Dijkstra(int s)
    {
        dist[s] = 0; //кратчайшее расстояние до стартовой вершины равно 0 
        for (int iter = 0; iter < n; ++iter)
        {
            int v = -1;
            int distV = INF;

            //выбираем вершину, кратчайшее расстояние до которого еще не найдено 
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                if (used[i])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (distV < dist[i])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                v = i;
                distV = dist[i];
            }
            //рассматриваем все дуги, исходящие из найденной вершины 
            for (int i = 0; i < adj[v].size(); ++i)
            {
                int u = adj[v].get(i);
                int weightU = weight[v].get(i);

                //релаксация вершины 
                if (dist[v] + weightU < dist[u])
                {
                    dist[u] = dist[v] + weightU;
                    pred[u] = v;
                }
            }
            //помечаем вершину v просмотренной, до нее найдено кратчайшее расстояние 
            used[v] = true;
        }
    }

    //процедура считывания входных данных с консоли 
    private void readData() throws IOException
    {
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(k);
        n = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()); //считываем количество вершин графа 
        m = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()); //считываем количество ребер графа 
        start = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()) - 1;

        //инициализируем списка смежности графа размерности n 
        adj = new ArrayList[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            adj[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }

        //инициализация списка, в котором хранятся веса ребер 
        weight = new ArrayList[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            weight[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(p);
        //считываем граф, заданный списком ребер 
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        {
            int u = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            int v = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            int w = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            u--;
            v--;
            adj[u].add(v);
            weight[u].add(w);
        }

        used = new boolean[n];
        Arrays.fill(used, false);

        pred = new int[n];
        Arrays.fill(pred, -1);

        dist = new int[n];
        Arrays.fill(dist, INF);

    }

    //процедура восстановления кратчайшего пути по массиву предком 
    void printWay(int v)
    {
        if (v == -1)
        {
            return;
        }
        printWay(pred[v]);
        res.answ.append(new String((v + 1) + " "));
    }

    //процедура вывода данных в консоль 
    private void printData() throws IOException
    {
        //Calculate units of time
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<dist.length; i++){
            if(max<dist[i])
                max = dist[i];
            if(min>dist[i])
                min = dist[i];
        }
        res.answ.setText("The best case: \nthe total time is " + max +  " units of time.\n\n");

        for (int v = 0; v < n; ++v)
        {
            if (dist[v] != INF)
            {
                res.answ.append(new String(dist[v] + " "));
            }
            else
            {
                res.answ.append(new String("No "));
            }
        }

        res.answ.append("\n\n");

        for (int v = 0; v < n; ++v)
        {
            res.answ.append(new String((v + 1) + ": "));
            if (dist[v] != INF)
            {
                printWay(v);
            }
            res.answ.append(new String("\n"));
        }
    }

    public void run() throws IOException
    {
        res = new Result();
        readData();
        Dijkstra(start);
        printData();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае задача является NP-трудной, но в случае когда граф ориентированный и ациклический, задача решается за линейное по числу рёбер время. Нужно заменить вес рёбер на противоположный (плюс на минус) и искать в графе кратчайший путь. В принципе, можно использовать алгоритм Дейкстры (работающий за квадрат от числа вершин), но можно использовать более простые алгоритмы за счёт ацикличности.

Например, выполняем топологическую сортировку: упорядочиваем все вершины в одну линию так, чтобы все рёбра шли строго слева направо (первые две картинки ниже).

Затем идём по очереди по вершинам и для каждой вершины `u`, для каждого ребра `(u,v)` делаем что-то вроде

```
if (dist[v] < dist[u] + weight(u, v))
  dist[v] = dist[u] + weight(u, v)
```

[image: Картинка]

Картинку и кусок кода я взял [здесь](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/). Там же по ссылке есть готовый код.

Comment: Может я чуть не так написал... в общем мне нужно найти максимальное и минимальное время за которое все элементы графа получат сигнал, при этом за одну единицу времени сигнал могут отправлять n количество НЕ связанных между собой элементов
т.е. на каждом уровне дерева элементы (к котороым уже дошел сигнал) могут работать одновременно.

Comment: Ну зашибись теперь :) Я ответил на вопрос, который вы задали, а если вы задали его "чуть" неправильно, что он превратился в совершенно другую задачу - то это уже как-то неприлично даже.