# Нахождение наибольшего количества ребер в пути графа?

Tags: java, алгоритм

У меня есть класс A, где хранятся данные узла графа.

```
public class A {
    int id;

    public Contour(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

        public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Есть матрица смежности

```
Map<Integer, Set<Contour>> adjMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Как мне найти наибольшее количество ребер из вершины до вершины, используя матрицу?

Comment: Задача недопоставлена. Что мешает при наличии цикла крутиться в нём бесконечно?

Comment: граф ориентированный. также предполагается, что циклов не будет в принципе

Comment: Случайно стёр комментарий. [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_о_самом_длинном_пути), [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614762/Найти-самый-длинный-путь-наибольшая-сумма-веса-ребер-в-графе)

Comment: В ориентированном ациклическом графе количество путей из вершины конечно. Так что обычный поиск - хоть в длину, хоть в ширину, и потом выбор самого длинного пути.